How to highlight fields for an OCR assist without distracting the user from the rest of the form?
Designing an OCR solution to assist healthcare claim assessors in reviewing claims for approval in a telehealth app. It will auto-fill certain fields using the info captured from  on document attachments. Colored tags indicate how accurately the characters have matched of each field (3 levels of accuracy)
The designs below shows how it would append to certian fields in the form. Consder if this soution is too prominant, it will distract the users from the rest of the information in the claim.
Which option do you think would be better for assessors to review claims fast and efficiently? what would be a better solution for this?


When you say "distract", what exactly do your users find distracting? Or is this just theoretical?
